# Setting 100% height on an absolutely positioned element when the content expands past the window size

Tags: height, css-position, css

So after reading Stack Overflow and the web, I've gathered that there are two main tricks to achieving 100% height:

1. Set height:100% on both the HTML and BODY
2. Set your element to have either:

   - height:100%, or
   - top:0, bottom:0, position:absolute

However, even with those tricks I'm having difficulty setting the height of an absolutely positioned DIV to a true 100%. I can get 100% of the viewport size, but if the user scrolls down at all it becomes apparent that the div doesn't truly have 100% height.

I've made a simple JS Fiddle of the situation here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9FEne/

My question is: does anyone know any further tricks to get a true (ie. content-height, not viewport-height) 100% height absolutely positioned div?

Comment: `position: relative`? `top: 0; bottom:0` would have *no* effect on a relatively positioned element.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder, no it wouldn't...  :)

Comment: Oh, well maybe that approach was supposed to use position: absolute.  I just know that position:absolute isn't working for me, but I've seen that top:0/bottom:0 technique somewhere ...

Comment: I guess what i meant to say was, you can still apply the `top`, `left` etc properties to relatively positioned elements. I think what you are trying to say is that setting it to `0` would have no effect since that's where it's at in the normal flow anyways.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder, that isn't what we are saying at all. Setting it to anything has no effect on relatively positioned elements. They default to "auto" (not zero) and setting them to zero (or anything else) has an effect, but only if you use position "absolute" or "fixed".

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder, for example, position:absolute; right:0; is very different then if you don't set the "right" value at all.  They definitely do not default to zero.

Comment: I've edited the question to be clearer; sorry for the confusion all.

Comment: To whoever is downvoting this question: if it's not too much to ask, could you please comment on what's wrong with this question?  It seems valid to me.

Comment: Prestaul, here's a `relatively` positioned element that has the `left` property applied to it http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/9FEne/6/

Comment: Upvote because this is a legitimate question, just worded very verbosely. The JS methods presented seem to work... does anyone know if there is a CSS-only way to do this?

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder, you're right. Relatively positioned elements are effected by left/right/etc as well, but very differently than absolutely positioned elements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry, I missed the real question before and thought you wanted the window filled.  If the issue is that the contents are longer than the window then what you need is to add `position:relative` to the body.  http://jsfiddle.net/9FEne/7/

What is happening is that when you absolutely position something it positions (and sizes) relative to the nearest positioned element. If you don't tell it to position to the body then it will position to the window.

Comment: It doesn't really work if there's no or too little content to fill screen's height. You might also want to add `height: 100%;` on both `body` and `html` elements.

Answer (score 7):

You can use jQuery to achieve this trick

```
var h = $(window).height();
$('#yourdiv').height(h);
```

Comment: This is a css question, not a javascript question.

Comment: Well you asked if there were "any further tricks". javascript could give an easy solution to this problem.

Comment: I'll say the same thing that I said to OnResolve: That is fair enough, but this is not difficult to solve with css and adding javascript into the mix introduces other issues... E.g. what happens when the user resizes his browser?

Comment: Also, you've missed the point of his question. He does not want to size to the window. He wants to size to the contents of his document.

Comment: You can easily detect when the window is resized with jQuery too, use the resize() method.

Comment: Ideally I would like to write a line or two of CSS, and just have the silly div stay 100% height no matter how big the user's monitor is, how big the content is, or whether or not the window gets resized.  That being said, unfortunately I have yet to see such a pure-CSS answer, so if one doesn't appear in a few hours I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I would use javascript to assign the height and width equal to document's height and window's width respectively; I've modified your jsfiddle to demonstrate it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9FEne/1/

Comment: Actually, if you read his question, there is nothing hinting at the fact that his solution needs to be css-only. In fact it sounds like he's exhausted css and still needs the the desired result.  Not sure why a different solution is worth a -1...seems like it would be best to have all options presented, no?

Comment: That is fair enough, but this is not difficult to solve with css and adding javascript into the mix introduces other issues...  E.g. what happens when the user resizes his browser?

Comment: You're both right: I was looking for a pure-CSS solution, but I did not in any way indicate that directly in the original question.  I'd still prefer a pure-CSS solution, but since none has appeared yet it looks like JS might be the only way.