# CSS div 100% height

Tags: css, height, css-position

I'm developing this [website](http://aquilewp.webkolm.com/grafica/) and I want the right sidebar to have 100% height.

```
body { 
    height: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

mydiv { 
    height: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    width: 290px;
}
```

I've read a lot of answer, especially this (Prestaul answer):
[Setting 100% height on an absolutely positioned element when the content expands past the window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146703/setting-100-height-on-an-absolutely-positioned-element-when-the-content-expands).

But for me this trick does not work, also the fiddle exemple doesn't work!

[This is the jsfiddle working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/9FEne/7/)

[This is the same code that doesn't work.](http://aquilewp.webkolm.com/grafica/prova.html)

Comment: Do you mean the couple of pixels white space at the top? Set your body's margin to `0` and it should work.

Comment: I wish your question was something like "CSS div 100% height for absolute-position element". It's a top search result but the scenario you have is more specific than the question. I am a moth to the incorrect flame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try setting the body style to:

```
body { position:relative;}
```

it worked for me

Comment: I've already do this as you can read,
http://aquilewp.webkolm.com/grafica/prova.html
here you can see the jsfiddle example put on my website... and it doesn't work

Comment: On the contrary, you have set the body style to `body {height:100%; min-height:100%; position:relative;}` I am suggesting you should set it to `body { position:relative;}`

Answer (score 56):

Set the html tag, too. This way no weird position hacks are required.

`html, body {height: 100%}`

Comment: I wonder why this is not the chosen answer? Setting body position to 'relative' is not a good practice however..!!

Comment: I tried this and it works like a charm. I was going to set a min-height for the div but it creates a scroll bar. This solution is most elegant.

Answer (score 7):

[CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) was designed to simplify creating these types of layouts.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.Content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.Sidebar {
  width: 290px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Content" style="background:#bed">Content</div>
<div class="Sidebar" style="background:#8cc">Sidebar</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This strategy works for me best:

```
div.full {
  width: 100wh;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

It creates a full screen container.

Answer (score 1):

I have another suggestion. When you want myDiv to have a height of 100%, use these extra 3 attributes on your div:

```
myDiv {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

That should do the job!